# angular 2 router.events subscription not firing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using a breadcrumbs component which make a subscription to router.events.
The problem is the first time the component is loaded, it does not fire the subscription.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log("oninit beradcumbs");
  this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
    this.breadcrumbs = [];
    let currentRoute = this.route.root,
    url = '';
    do {
      const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
      currentRoute = null;
      childrenRoutes.forEach(route => {
        if (route.outlet === 'primary') {
          const routeSnapshot = route.snapshot;
          url += '/' + routeSnapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
          this.breadcrumbs.push({
            label: route.snapshot.data,
            url:   url
          });
          currentRoute = route;
        }
      });
    } while (currentRoute);
    console.log("Breadcumbs",this.breadcrumbs);
  });
}
```

When a link with routerLink property is clicked, the subscription emits the values and it works fine.
I compared my project with a working one with Augury and in the breadcrumb component, the state of Router looks like this: [Not working Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uWPZ.png)

And the working one: [Working router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNHnd.png)

Let me now if you need more info to help :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: put this code inside the constructor()

Comment: @Vega Yes it works! but I don't understand why. I'm using same code that the other project for this component

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is loading data asynchronously via subscribe. I suggested to put it in constructor(), so it will be executed before the lifecycle hook thus before OnInit(), and data will be loaded before you click on the link. Which was right. 
So look to Observables more closely to understand better what is going on.

Comment: Thanks you! I know about observables but had some doubts on why router.events is emiting before the component can capture the value since it is a shared component and is instanciated on bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

Not firing router subscription events after lifecycle hook is there in Angular 9  as well. According to a contributor [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17473#issuecomment-308848113), there is no guarantee for the sequence of router events interleaving with the component lifecycle hooks.

We can do a simple test to identify when the router events fire.

```
constructor(private router: Router) { 
   console.log('constructor')
   this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => 
       event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
         console.log(event);
   });
 }

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('ngOnInit')
}
```

You will see on the console that router event is printed on the console before the 'ngOnInit' gets printed. So the right place to subscribe to the router events is the constructor.